# How to use pd.grouper along with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe

```
    S2PName-Category    S2BillDate  totSale
0   Food               2019-05-18   2150.0
1   Beverages          2019-05-19   403.0
2   Food               2019-05-19   7254.0
3   Others             2019-05-19   200.0
4   Juice              2019-05-19   125.0
5   Snacks             2019-05-19   70.0
6   Food               2019-06-21   11932.0
```

I want to group by s2PName-category and group s2Billdate by freq(monthly or weekly or day) and agg totsale

ie if I groupby Billdate with freq as monthly, then my resul df shld have 'Food' for the months 'may' and 'june' with their total sale summed up.

I managed to write some code which is like below,

```
basic_df = basic_df.groupby(['S2PName-Category','S2BillDate'], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum')]).reset_index()
```

Expected DF output:

```
  S2PName-Category    S2BillDate  totSale
0   Food               2019-05-31   9404.0
1   Beverages          2019-05-31   403.0
3   Others             2019-05-31   200.0
4   Juice              2019-05-31   125.0
5   Snacks             2019-05-31   70.0
6   Food               2019-06-30   11932.0
```

In my expected o/p df , I have the s2Billdate set to last day of the month and totSale agg for that month.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
basic_df_2 = basic_df.groupby(['S2PName-Category',basic_df['S2BillDate'].dt.to_period('M')], sort=False)['S2PGTotal'].agg([('totSale','sum')]).reset_index()
```

dt.to_period will help in taking up arguments related to frequency !